# An error when trying to install a package related to R version

Tags: r

I am trying to install the package `ggpubr` using the command `install.packages('ggpubr')` but I'm getting the error:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/nasser/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘cowplot’ is not available
```

I then tried to install the package `cowplot` using `install.packages('cowplot')` command and again I got the following error `Warning in install.packages :  package ‘cowplot’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)`

I searched for a solution and found a suggestion to use the following command:

```
devtools::install_github("wilkelab/cowplot")
```

and I got this error `ERROR: this R is version 3.4.4, package 'cowplot' requires R >= 3.5.0`

After a long time searching for a solution, I ended up having no perfect solution.

Can you please suggest me a way to avoid this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Answer (score 1):

You have version 3.4.4 of R installed. The package `cowplot` requires version 3.5.0 or higher. You must upgrade your version of R.

Sometimes this is not possible (such as on a work network). In these cases, an alternative is to install an older version of `cowplot` that does not have that requirement. Of course, this means you are using an older version of the package. Archives are available on CRAN for older package versions.

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/cowplot/